# Complex Vector Spaces and Real Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces

Can any system that is represented using a complex vector space also be represented using a real vector space of double the dimensions?

Comment: yes, but you lose significant (skalar multiplicative structure for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$) structure (just interpret the vectorspace as $\mathbb{R}$ vectorspace via the inclusion $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$).

Comment: ... and dimensions of sub-spaces all double e.g the line $(t, it)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ becomes a plane $(u,v,-v,u)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspaces  and therefore we have $\mathbb{C}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspaces.

Comment: Does this mean quantum mechanics could have been re-expressed using only real numbers?